# Multiple AJAX RSS readers on a single page?

Tags: php, ajax, rss

I haven't posted on here before but I have tried to do some research before posting so that I didn't waste anyone's time but I haven't found that anyone posted with a similar problem.

I have this problem with getting two RSS feeds on one page, I have edited the http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp example. Basically when I call both from the html onload="runscripts();"
functions :
                showRSS('Google');
            rssevents('events');
Only one of them populates the DIV. I did get it working side my side but occasionally one feed would populate the other DIV even though the variables are completely different.

Essentially I have doubled the code up and created different variables so that hopefully i would have two rss feeds on my single page? But it doesn't work.

Any help would be welcome :) even to point me in the right direction! Cheers :)

heres the code:

body on load calls both functions:

```
function runscripts(){  
        showRSS('Google');
        rssevents('events');        
}
```

Javascript header:

```
function showRSS(str)
    {
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    if(str=='Google')
    {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

    else{
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("upcomingevents").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getrssEvents.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }



    }
    function rssevents(str)
    {
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("upcomingevents").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }



    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }



    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("upcomingevents").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }



    xmlhttp.open("GET","getrssEvents.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Php code:

getrss.php:

```
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="Google")
  {
  $xml=("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");
  }
elseif($q=="MSNBC")
  {
  $xml=("http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml");
  }

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(1)->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(1)->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(1)->childNodes->item(1)->nodeValue;


//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$k=4;
$findme = '<img src';

for ($i=1; $i<=$k; $i++)
  {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $pos = strpos($item_desc,$findme);

  if($pos==false)
  {
      $k=$k+1;
  }
  else{
  echo ("<p><div class='rsstitle' style='height:120px;'><div class='rsstable2'>" . $item_desc); 
  echo ("</div><div class='rsstable'><a href='" . $item_link . "' target='_blank'>" . $item_title . "</a></div></div><p/>");
  }

  }
?>
```

getrssEvents.php:

```
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="Google")
  {
  $xml=("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");
  }
elseif($q=="events")
  {
  $xml=("http://groupspaces.com/LoughboroughFinanceSociety/api/events?alt=rss");
  }

$xmlDoc2 = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc2->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc2->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('summary')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
//$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('gs:location')
//->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc2->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
  {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('summary')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  //$item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('gs')
  ///->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  //echo ("<div class='rsstitle'>" . $item_desc);   
  //echo ("<a  href='" . $item_link . "'>" . $item_title . "</a></div><p/>");
    echo(" <div class='rssevents'><div class='rsseventtitle'> ".$item_title."</div>". $item_link."</div>");

  }
?>
```

Cheers for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AJAX functions, you need to put the sequential code (could be another AJAX function) in the callback on the first AJAX function. This ensures that the 2nd call is made after the first one is complete. 
Else, the sequential code, may get executed before the 1st AJAX function finishes.

Comment: GIVE THIS MAN SOME STACK OVERFLOW POINTS!!!! :)

I placed the second function call in the callback and it worked first time.